# Examples on isomorphism and homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Could someone please explain to me how isomorphisms and homomorphisms work?

For an isomorphism, I know we need to follow the following four steps:

$\ \ \ $1) define a candidate,

$\ \ \ $2) show it is $1$-$1$

$\ \ \ $3) show it is onto

$\ \ \ $4) show it is closed.

But, I don't know how to actually apply it if we are given a question like what should I be focusing on.

And the same for homomorphisms.

Any help with examples would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "question like that"? Like what, exactly?

Comment: like phi(a)*phi(b) = phi(ab)

Comment: like just any random example that would help me understand how this isomorphism actually works

Comment: it's good to imagine isomorphism as "translation" from one language to another. For example "소고기" and "beef" look different, but they mean the same thing in Korean and English respectively.

Answer (score 4):

For an isomorphism take the symmetries of a regular pentagon, and the symmetries of the five-pointed star obtained by joining alternate vertices of the pentagon. Every symmetry of the pentagon converts into a symmetry of the star, and vice-versa. Although the two figures look different their symmetries are the same. That's an isomorphism.

For a homomorphism consider the integers and split them into even and odd numbers as if whether they are even or odd is all that matters. We have E+E = O+O = ExE = OxE = ExO = E; and O+E = E+O = OxO = O. We have abstracted a feature of these numbers (oddness or evenness) in such a way that it respects the original arithmetic - the multiplication and addition. That's a homomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(A,\triangle)$ and $(B,\triangledown)$ be groups. $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a homomorphism if $\forall x,y\in A$

$$ f(x\triangle y) = f(x)\triangledown f(y) $$

This is basically saying that $f$ preserves the group structure when it maps element of $A$ to elements of $B$. Homomorphisms tell us about the similarities between two groups.

For example, take the integers under addition modulo 2 and 4, $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_4$. Let $f:\mathbb Z_2 \rightarrow \{0,2\} \subset \mathbb Z_4$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1) = 2$. $f$ is a homomorphism (note that it is injective). Since the two groups are abelian it suffices to show that
$$\begin{align}
&f(0+_20) = f(0)+_4f(0) = 0+_40 = 0 = f(0) \\
&f(0+_21) = f(0)+_4f(1) = 0+_42 = 2 = f(1) \\
&f(1+_21) = f(1)+_4f(1) = 2+_42 = 0 = f(0)
\end{align}$$

This tells us that the structure $\mathbb Z_2$ is equivalent to the structure of the subgroup $\{0,2\}$ of $\mathbb Z_4$.

It is important to note that homomorphisms fix the identity element. If $e$ is the identity element in $A$ and $x \in A$ then $f(x\triangle e) = f(x)\triangledown f(e)$ and $f(x\triangle e) = f(x)$ (simplifying inside of $f$). So, $f(e)$ must be the identity element for $B$.

An *isomorphism* is a bijective homomorphism. If two groups are isomorphic they have the same group structure.

An *epimorphism* is a surjective homomorphism. If there is an epimorphism from $A$ to $B$, it implies that $B$ is isomorphic to some quotient group of $A$.

A *monomorphism* is an injective homomorphism. A monomorphism from $A$ to $B$ implies that $A$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $B$ (as we saw above).